# Oauth 2.0 validity of refresh_token in Box v2 API

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api

The oauth docs says
**Each access_token is valid for 1 hour and each refresh token is valid for 14 days. To use the refresh_token to get a new access_token, make a POST request to https://api.box.com/oauth2/token**

**In this response, you’ll receive both a new access_token and refresh_token. The refresh_token you used to make this request is *no longer valid*.**

Questions:
1) If by chance I am not able to store this new refresh_token then the old refresh_token is invalidated?

2) Can't there be refresh token which is valid always and we generate only access_token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, when a new refresh_token is created, the previous one is invalidated.
2. Part of the OAuth 2 spec includes invalidating old refresh_tokens in exchange for a new one. It's not the most gripping read, but you can see all of that here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31

Comment: So what will happen if we fail to save the refresh_token and use the old refresh_token again?

Comment: It will give you an error about your refresh_token being invalid.  Once you use a refresh, it's considered used up, as per the OAuth2 specification.

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem. You get a new refresher when you get the new tokon. So keep it in memory or serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we just changed this so that we don't get rid of your old refresh token until you've used the new access token.